# Estou tentando escrever um programa que calcula o percentual mensal de uma distribuidora

Tags: python

Tentei resolver isso em Python mas não rolou eu já estou a tantas horas nisso que nem consigo mais pensar então resolvi erguer a mão. O exercício é esse:

> Dado o valor de faturamento mensal de uma distribuidora, detalhado abaixo por estado:
>
> SP – R$67.836,43
>
> RJ – R$36.678,66
>
> MG – R$29.229,88
>
> ES – R$27.165,48
>
> Outros – R$19.849,53
>
> Escreva um programa na linguagem que desejar onde calcule o percentual de representação que cada estado teve dentro do valor de faturamento total mensal da distribuidora.

O que eu escrevi em Python:

```
sp = float(67.83643)
rj = float(36.67866)
mg = float(29.22988)
es = float(27.16548)
out = float(19.84953)
total = float(sp + rj + mg + es + out)
print(total)
psp = ((sp*total)/100)
prj = ((rj*total)/100)
pmg = ((mg*total)/100)
pes = ((es*total)/100)
pout = ((out*total)/100)

print('Porcentagem de SP {}'.format(psp))
print('Porcentagem de RJ {}'.format(prj))
print('Porcentagem de MG {}'.format(pmg))
print('Porcentagem de ES {}'.format(pes))
print('Porcentagem de OUT {}'.format(pout))
```

Comment: Detalhe: fazer  `float(67.83643)` é redundante, basta usar o número `67.8343` diretamente. O mesmo vale pro `total`

Answer (score 2):

Seu problema está na fórmula de percentual. Você deve dividir o valor de um estado pelo total e não multiplicá-lo. Depois multiplicar por 100% para encontrar a porcentagem (você inverteu os operadores):

```py
sp = float(67.83643)
rj = float(36.67866)
mg = float(29.22988)
es = float(27.16548)
out = float(19.84953)
total = float(sp + rj + mg + es + out)
print(total)
psp = ((sp/total)*100)
prj = ((rj/total)*100)
pmg = ((mg/total)*100)
pes = ((es/total)*100)
pout = ((out/total)*100)

print('Porcentagem de SP {}'.format(psp))
print('Porcentagem de RJ {}'.format(prj))
print('Porcentagem de MG {}'.format(pmg))
print('Porcentagem de ES {}'.format(pes))
print('Porcentagem de OUT {}'.format(pout))
```

Answer (score 0):

Imagine que você tenha que calcular **mensalmente** esses valores. Neste caso, você tem que implementar a função `input()` para receber esses valores **cada mês** que precisar.

Outra coisa o cálculo de `percentagem` que desejas calcular neste programa é uma `percentagem relativa`. Nesta situação você precisa calcular a percentagem de `cada estado` em função do `faturamento total`.

Diante destas observação implementei o seguinte algoritmo...

```
# Definindo os estados para uma melhor manipulação:
e = ['SP', 'RJ', 'MG', 'ES', 'OUTROS']

faturamento = list()
for c in e:
    # Capturando e tratando os valores digitados:
    while True:
        try:
            v = float(input(f'Digite o faturamento mensal de {c}: '))
            if v < 0:
                print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas valores maiores ou iguais a "0":\033[m')
            break
        except:
            print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas valores reais!\033[m')

    # Armazenando os valores digitados na lista faturamento
    faturamento.append(v)

# Calculando o faturamento total da distribuidora:
faturamento_total = sum(faturamento)
print(f'\033[32mO faturamento total da Distribuidora foi: R$ {faturamento_total:.2f}'.replace('.', ','))

# Calculando e exibindo o percentual relativo de cada filial de cada estado:
cont = 0
for i in faturamento:
    cont += 1
    percentual = ((i / faturamento_total) * 100)
    print(f'O percentual de faturamento de {e[cont - 1]} é: {percentual:.2f} %')
```

[Veja aqui](https://repl.it/join/wlbrftcs-solkarped) o funcionamento do programa.

Observe que a primeira coisa que implementei neste programa foi uma `lista`. Pois, nela ficarão armazenados as siglas dos `estados`, exceto o último que é `outros`.

Depois criei um bloco de códigos onde serão `capturados` e `tratados` cada valor digitado.

**Observe que para este algoritmo funcionar corretamente os valores digitados terão de ser da seguinte forma xx.xxxxx**, ou seja, para você inserir o valor `R$ 67.836,43`, você terá que digitar...

```
67.83643
```

Se cada valor digitado estiver correto, o mesmo será inserido na lista `faturamento`.

Em seguida o programa calcula o `faturamento total` da distribuidora. Este faturamento total é a soma de todos os faturamentos obtidos por cada filial.

Posteriormente é calculado o percentual relativo de cada `filia` em função do `faturamento total`.